# Rails Convert DateTime to Excel Format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to convert the DateTime to meet Excel's Requirement for formatting cells:
http://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/microsoft-office-xml-tip-use-the-correct-format-for-the-datetime-data-type-to-avoid-error

With strftime http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime i can't see the fff part.

How can i convert DateTime.now into this excel compatible format?

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff
```

especially the fraction of the seconds fff.

Answer (score 4):

If you need get a string in correct format you can use [striftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) method:

```
DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L")
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander, that's great! But where did you find the %L argument? apidock doesn't have it documented.

Comment: You should view  this link: http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime. It's present there

Comment: Ah, thanks! I looked on the wrong page http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime

Comment: Not at all. Actually you looked on Rails Time#strftime hook.